# WordPress main navigation - split into two rows?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigationbar

Trying to get the main nav to sit on two rows like this (with the second row having a coloured background:[menu mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjIBk.jpg)

Ideas? I was able to split the two rows by placing /ul ul tags in the menu structure (at the end of the menu item that was to be the last in the top row), but still trying to figure out how to customize the colour of that background/ fonts, and without modifying the current menu that is at the [very top of the page.](https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/)

TIA!

```
<header id="main-header" data-height-onload="147" data-height-loaded="true" data-fixed-height-onload="117" style="top: 63px;">
            <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
                            <div class="logo_container">
                    <span class="logo_helper"></span>
                    <a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/">
                        <img src="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/SMBWEBMAIN.png" alt="Discover St. Margarets Bay" id="logo" data-height-percentage="54" data-actual-width="703" data-actual-height="150">
                    </a>
                </div>
                            <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="66" data-fixed-height="40">
                                            <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav gd-menu-z"><li id="menu-item-1742" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-1742"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1379" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1379"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/explore-the-bay/">Explore the Bay</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1381" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1365 current_page_item menu-item-1381" aria-current="true"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/family-living/">Family Living</a><span class="screen-reader-text">(current)</span><span class="screen-reader-text">(current)</span></li>
<li id="menu-item-1380" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1380"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/shop-local/">Shop Local</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1382" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1382"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/contact-us/">Learn More</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1643" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1643"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/events-calendar/">Events Calendar</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1644" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1644"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/the-directory/">Services Directory</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1670" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1670"><a href="https://dev.discoverstmargaretsbay.com/community-forums/">Community Forums</a></li>
</ul>                       </nav>
```

Comment: If it were me I'd probably create 2 navigation menus in the theme and add the links to the primary or secondary menu as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already gone through your site and code. Your code causing issue so its better to consider two different "div" for logo and menu area. By doing this, you can edit menu area accordingly and then create 2 "ul".

You can visit my blog to get your answer: [Online IN World](http://www.onlineinworld.com/split-your-navigation-menu-into-2-rows/). Here is the code I would suggest for splitting things into two dvis

```
<div class=”container logo_sec”>
<!– Logo Area or Header Area which includes logo and top bar with contact info –>
LOGO Section
</div>
<div class=”container-fluid”>
<div class=”row”>
<ul class=”main_header_1″>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 1 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 2 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 3 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 4 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 5 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class=”row”>
<ul class=”main_header_2″>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 1 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 2 </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Menu 3 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
/* CSS goes here */
body
{
margin: 0;
}
.logo_sec
{
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
}
.main_header_1
{
background-color: #ffffff;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.main_header_1 li,
.main_header_2 li
{
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
}
.main_header_1 li a
{
color: #333333;
}
.main_header_1 li a,
.main_header_2 li a
{
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
}
.main_header_2
{
background-color: darkblue;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.main_header_2 li a
{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

So you will get output like this as I already mentioned the code to split menu into 2 rows.

[Check this image for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THLhy.png)

Thank you.

Comment: @Makyen removed the content and restored. You are right. Author should do it if he does not consider a copyright issue and wants to share freely.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting access to the template that is being used and will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have them in two different divs? May be a better approach to edit each other.

OR you could do ul:nth-child(even){background-color:blue}

Showing your HTMl may make it easier.

Comment: I'm just working from the Divi builder in WordPress on a template that was created for the site right now. Was trying to figure out if there was an easier way then going into the code and changing the template, but that might have to be the case! Getting access to the ftp then will show the code. Thanks!

Comment: See edited post above... is there any way to do this with just adding in css vs. messing with the template html?